# Laravel 5 - Extract emails from array?

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I've looked around but didn't find a solution or a way to do this in Laravel out of the box, so I am wondering if there is way to do this:

I have an `$emails` array, where 2 emails are valid and 1 is invalid:

```
$emails = ["apple@fruits.com","banana@fruits.com","apple.com","banana"];

// How can I get the following 2 arrays using Laravel?
$validEmails = ["apple@fruits.com","banana@fruits.com"];
$invalidEmails = ["apple.com","banana"];
```

How can I get the last 2 arrays using Laravel from the `$emails` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't need Laravel for this.

```
$validEmails = [];
$invalidEmails = [];
foreach ($emails as $email){
   if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         $validEmails[] = $email;
   }
   else
   {
         $invalidEmails[] = $email;
   }
}
```

[Note : It will work after PHP 5.2]